# R: How to change column type of a df in a list and combine list to df with bind_rows()

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr

I´m having multiple dataframes/tibbles inside a list, like this: (in the real dataset it´s more like 500 df with 180 columns and 30 rows each)

```
df1 <- data.frame(Col_1 = c(0,0,0,0,0),
                  Col_2 = c(1,1,1,1,1),
                  Col_3 = c("text", "text", "text", "text", "text"))

df2 <- data.frame(Col_1 = c(0,0,0,0,0),
                  Col_2 = c(1,1,1,1,1),
                  Col_3 = c(2,2,2,2,2))
l <- list(df1, df2)
```

The reason for this is, because I´m using readxl over multiple excel files. In principle those excel files/columns are the same, but some columns are imported as character or double. This is caused by user input.

In the end I want a big dataframe with all the df binded by `bind_rows()` or another function.

By simply using `dplyr::bind_rows(l)` there will be an error (`` Error: Can't combine `..1$Col_3` <character> and `..2$Col_3` <double>. ``), because I´m having different class types. To solve this problem, I´m using this approach:

```
l <- lapply(l, function(df) dplyr::mutate_at(df, vars(matches("Col_3")), as.character))
```

and afterwards this:

```
df <- dplyr::bind_rows(l)
```

which results in my desired df using this simple example.

BUT if I want to use the lapply function in my "real" dataset, this error always occurs:

```
Error: Can't transform a data frame with duplicate names.
```

1. How could I enclose the problem? (I can´t share the dataset because of confidentiality reasons, but I couldn´t reproduce this error in the above mentioned example)
2. Is there maybe a better way/function to convert this list into one df? Maybe convert automatically all column types to character (for now this would work, but this is of course not a good choice in the long run)

Comment: Do you know the "truth" of data class? If you know that `Col_3` here should always be `character`, then focus on how you import the data the first time. The fact that `bind_rows` is protecting you from inadvertent combination of incompatible data classes is not something I would encouraging idly side-stepping.

Comment: If you're okay with discarding the safeguards (of column name, position, and class), then you can do simply `do.call(rbind, l)`, and you get the results you're asking for.

Comment: This results in the same error:
`do.call(rbind, l)
Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names`

Comment: [edit] your question and fix your data, please. We can only help based on what we know, and you provided data where that problem was not the case.

Comment: The problem is, I _can´t_ reproduce my problem using an example dataset, if I´m not sure what the error `Error: Can't transform a data frame with duplicate names.` is trying to tell me..

Comment: Change one of the names in one of the frames you have in your sample data, then run my code and you get that error. That suggests that in your real data, one of the names is not what you think it is. Try `table(unlist(lapply(l, names)))`; if you are correct, then all names will have the same count; if not, then you have more information.

Comment: Thank you very much for this function! With this I can now scroll through the names and maybe can find my name, which is giving me my error :-)
A question besides my original question:
How can I delete certain columns from the list before I merge them into the df using row_bind()? During the readxl function some columns are created with names like *...187* or *__199* and I want to delete them beforehand.

Comment: `lapply(l, function(x) subset(x , select = setdiff(names(x), names_to_del)))`

Comment: Thank you very much. One follow up question: 
Is there a way to delete all the matching columns with a given character string? Like `matches("___") or `matches("...")`?

Comment: It's however you want to generate `names_to_del`. `unique(grep(ptn, unlist(lapply(l, names)), value=TRUE))` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Change everything columns to `character`, and then you can combine the data frames.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df_all <- map_dfr(l, ~.x %>% mutate(across(everything(), as.character)))
```

A better way could be that when you read the data into R, make sure all columns are `character`.

Comment: This results in the same error
`Error: Can't transform a data frame with duplicate names.`

Comment: I applied your example to my code and I did not encounter this error. Perhaps clean your work space and recreate your example to test the code.

Comment: With my example above I also did not encounter this error. But I want to identify the problem in my real dataset. I don´t know what happens there. Is there a better way to enclose my problem in the dataset without posting it here?

Comment: If I cannot see your real-word example, I have no ideas how to help as I don't have magic or super powers. It is strange that you posted an example that does not reflect the nature or characteristic of your real-world data.

Answer (score 0):

Up front, the best fix for this is to specify the column class when importing the data. By far, the function I propose below should never be used when you have any semblance of control over the import process. The utility of this function is in the extreme times you need some normalization of classes.

```r
normalize_attributes <- function(L) {
  all_nms <- unique(unlist(sapply(L, names)))
  L <- lapply(L, function(dat) {
    missing_nms <- setdiff(all_nms, names(dat))
    if (length(missing_nms)) dat[missing_nms] <- NA
    dat
  })
  first_nms <- names(L[[1]])

  reattrib_funcs <- setNames(vector("list", length(all_nms)), all_nms)

  LL_attr <- lapply(setNames(nm = all_nms),
                    function(nm) lapply(L, function(dat) attributes(dat[[nm]])))
  LL_first <- lapply(setNames(nm = all_nms),
                     function(nm) lapply(L, function(dat) dat[[nm]][1]))

  for (nm in all_nms) {
    haschr <- sapply(LL_first[[nm]], inherits, "character")
    hasnum <- sapply(LL_first[[nm]], inherits, "numeric")
    haspsx <- sapply(LL_first[[nm]], inherits, "POSIXt")
    hasdate <- sapply(LL_first[[nm]], inherits, "Date")
    # use psx if any present otherwise date
    hastime <- if (any(haspsx)) haspsx else hasdate

    if (any(haschr)) {
      # character wins all
      reattrib_funcs[[nm]] <- as.character
    } else if (any(hastime)) {
      # need to use attributes here; this allows up-conversion without
      # needing to specify the 'origin' (this might be a bug!)
      att <- LL_attr[[nm]][[ which.max(hastime) ]]
      reattrib_funcs[[nm]] <- substitute(function(vec) `attributes<-`(vec, att))
    } else if (any(hasnum)) {
      reattrib_funcs[[nm]] <- as.numeric
    } else {
      cls <- class(unlist(LL_first[[nm]]))
      reattrib_funcs[[nm]] <- substitute(function(vec) `class<-`(vec, cls))
    }
  }

  L <- lapply(L, function(dat) {
    dat[all_nms] <- Map(function(func, vec) eval(func)(vec),
                        reattrib_funcs[all_nms], dat[all_nms])
    dat
  })

}
```

Some cruel data, showing various combinations of data classes/types:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(int_int = c(0L,0L,0L,0L,0L),
                  num_num = c(0,0,0,0,0),
                  num_int = c(0,0,0,0,0),
                  num_psx = c(0,0,0,0,0),
                  num_dat = c(0,0,0,0,0),
                  chr_num = c("text", "text", "text", "text", "text"),
                  psx_dat = rep(Sys.time(),5),
                  chr_mis = c(0,0,0,0,0))

df2 <- data.frame(int_int = c(1L,1L,1L,1L,1L),
                  num_num = c(1,1,1,1,1),
                  num_int = c(1L,1L,1L,1L,1L),
                  num_psx = rep(Sys.time(),5),
                  num_dat = rep(Sys.Date(),5),
                  psx_dat = rep(Sys.Date(),5),
                  chr_num = c(1,1,1,1,1))

l <- list(df1, df2)
str(l)
# List of 2
#  $ :'data.frame': 5 obs. of  8 variables:
#   ..$ int_int: int [1:5] 0 0 0 0 0
#   ..$ num_num: num [1:5] 0 0 0 0 0
#   ..$ num_int: num [1:5] 0 0 0 0 0
#   ..$ num_psx: num [1:5] 0 0 0 0 0
#   ..$ num_dat: num [1:5] 0 0 0 0 0
#   ..$ chr_num: chr [1:5] "text" "text" "text" "text" ...
#   ..$ psx_dat: POSIXct[1:5], format: "2021-02-11 10:51:52" "2021-02-11 10:51:52" "2021-02-11 10:51:52" "2021-02-11 10:51:52" ...
#   ..$ chr_mis: num [1:5] 0 0 0 0 0
#  $ :'data.frame': 5 obs. of  7 variables:
#   ..$ int_int: int [1:5] 1 1 1 1 1
#   ..$ num_num: num [1:5] 1 1 1 1 1
#   ..$ num_int: int [1:5] 1 1 1 1 1
#   ..$ num_psx: POSIXct[1:5], format: "2021-02-11 10:51:52" "2021-02-11 10:51:52" "2021-02-11 10:51:52" "2021-02-11 10:51:52" ...
#   ..$ num_dat: Date[1:5], format: "2021-02-11" "2021-02-11" "2021-02-11" "2021-02-11" ...
#   ..$ psx_dat: Date[1:5], format: "2021-02-11" "2021-02-11" "2021-02-11" "2021-02-11" ...
#   ..$ chr_num: num [1:5] 1 1 1 1 1
```

(The column names indicate the different types/classes.) Note the problems with those frames:

- `"chr_mis"` is missing in one;
- columns are in a different order, `"chr_num"` notably; and obviously
- the classes are rarely the same :-)

I expect from this that:

- if any column is a string, all frames have that column as a string;
- if a column is `POSIXt` or `Date` (special-case `numeric` due to attributes), all should be;
- `num` and `int` go to `num`, normal R behavior;
- missing columns are added, using the appropriate R `NA` class (there are at least six types of `NA`)

And the fixed data:

```r
str(l2 <- normalize_attributes(l))
# List of 2
#  $ :'data.frame': 5 obs. of  8 variables:
#   ..$ int_int: int [1:5] 0 0 0 0 0
#   ..$ num_num: num [1:5] 0 0 0 0 0
#   ..$ num_int: num [1:5] 0 0 0 0 0
#   ..$ num_psx: POSIXct[1:5], format: "1969-12-31 19:00:00" "1969-12-31 19:00:00" "1969-12-31 19:00:00" "1969-12-31 19:00:00" ...
#   ..$ num_dat: Date[1:5], format: "1970-01-01" "1970-01-01" "1970-01-01" "1970-01-01" ...
#   ..$ chr_num: chr [1:5] "text" "text" "text" "text" ...
#   ..$ psx_dat: POSIXct[1:5], format: "2021-02-11 11:43:31" "2021-02-11 11:43:31" "2021-02-11 11:43:31" "2021-02-11 11:43:31" ...
#   ..$ chr_mis: num [1:5] 0 0 0 0 0
#  $ :'data.frame': 5 obs. of  8 variables:
#   ..$ int_int: int [1:5] 1 1 1 1 1
#   ..$ num_num: num [1:5] 1 1 1 1 1
#   ..$ num_int: num [1:5] 1 1 1 1 1
#   ..$ num_psx: POSIXct[1:5], format: "2021-02-11 11:43:31" "2021-02-11 11:43:31" "2021-02-11 11:43:31" "2021-02-11 11:43:31" ...
#   ..$ num_dat: Date[1:5], format: "2021-02-11" "2021-02-11" "2021-02-11" "2021-02-11" ...
#   ..$ psx_dat: POSIXct[1:5], format: "1970-01-01 00:11:09" "1970-01-01 00:11:09" "1970-01-01 00:11:09" "1970-01-01 00:11:09" ...
#   ..$ chr_num: chr [1:5] "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
#   ..$ chr_mis: num [1:5] NA NA NA NA NA
```

which can now be `rbind`ed more safely:

```r
do.call(rbind, l2)
#    int_int num_num num_int             num_psx    num_dat chr_num             psx_dat chr_mis
# 1        0       0       0 1969-12-31 19:00:00 1970-01-01    text 2021-02-11 11:43:31       0
# 2        0       0       0 1969-12-31 19:00:00 1970-01-01    text 2021-02-11 11:43:31       0
# 3        0       0       0 1969-12-31 19:00:00 1970-01-01    text 2021-02-11 11:43:31       0
# 4        0       0       0 1969-12-31 19:00:00 1970-01-01    text 2021-02-11 11:43:31       0
# 5        0       0       0 1969-12-31 19:00:00 1970-01-01    text 2021-02-11 11:43:31       0
# 6        1       1       1 2021-02-11 11:43:31 2021-02-11       1 1970-01-01 00:11:09      NA
# 7        1       1       1 2021-02-11 11:43:31 2021-02-11       1 1970-01-01 00:11:09      NA
# 8        1       1       1 2021-02-11 11:43:31 2021-02-11       1 1970-01-01 00:11:09      NA
# 9        1       1       1 2021-02-11 11:43:31 2021-02-11       1 1970-01-01 00:11:09      NA
# 10       1       1       1 2021-02-11 11:43:31 2021-02-11       1 1970-01-01 00:11:09      NA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library dplyr
library purr
```

I would first create a list of all the files to be combined

```
csv_files = list.files(path = (paste0(data_path,"folder_with_csvs/")), pattern = "csv$", full.names = TRUE)
```

Then choose from the following options (second is probably preferred).
First option is to have every column as a character.

```
df_all <- map_dfr(.x = set_names(csv_files),
              .f = ~ read_csv(.x, col_types = cols(.default = "c")))
```

Second option is have the default parsing/guessing for all columns except your exception(s).

```
df_all <- map_dfr(.x = set_names(csv_files_new),
          .f = ~ read_csv(.x, col_types = cols(.default = "?",Col_3 = "c")))
```

Third option is it classify each column.

```
df_all <- map_dfr(.x = set_names(csv_files_new),
              .f = ~ read_csv(.x, col_types = cols(Col_1 = "c", #char
                                                   Col_2 = "d", #double
                                                   Col_3 = "c"))) #char
```

see p. 34 of http://www.hiercourse.com/docs/Working_in_the_Tidyverse.pdf for more details